# how to delete products of attributeset programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, products-management

I am adding products by code in particular one attributeset named "Diamond".

I had programmed a cron job to add the csv data as products in "Diamond" attribute set. The new csv uploaded on daily bases.

So, I want to remove the previously added products from "Diamond" atribute set.

Any idea to delete those products which attribute set is "Diamond" by code?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Magento get all products by attribute set](http://magentocookbook.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/magento-get-all-products-by-attribute-set/)

```
//Fetch attribute set id by attribute set name
$attrSetName = 'Diamond';
$attributeSetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->load($attrSetName, 'attribute_set_name')
    ->getAttributeSetId();

//Load product model collection filtered by attribute set id
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);

//process your product collection as per your business logic
$productsName = array();
foreach($products as $p){
    $productsName[] = $p->getData('name');
    //uncomment $p->delete(); after verifying these are the correct products  
    //$p->delete();
}

print_r($productsName);
```

Comment: Did this code work for you?